# Why can't I extend IntegerType?

Tags: swift, extension-methods

All over the web, including here, I see example after example of extending the protocol `IntegerType` (Docs here: [IntegerType](https://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/integertype/)) in swift, like so...

```
import Foundation

extension IntegerType {

    var bla:Bool{
        return true
    }
}
```

However, the above doesn't compile for me and gives me the following error:

> Use of undeclared type 'IntegerType'

I've also tried the following with no luck...

```
extension Numeric where Self == IntegerType {

    var bla:Bool{
        return true
    }
}

extension Numeric where Self:IntegerType {

    var bla:Bool{
        return true
    }
}

extension Numeric where self is IntegerType {

    var bla:Bool{
        return true
    }
}
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Aaaah.  Looks like it was deprecated starting with Swift 3.0.  Grepped that from the full link to the docs...

https://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/integertype

It doesn't seem to exist after 3.0